# ulimit seems to freeze bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ulimit, glibc

I'm running a bash script that runs multiple small apps with different inputs. Some of these apps have bugs (e.g., never finish) and so I use ulimit to get the output or an error from all of them.

In "pseudo-bash" is something like this:

```
for app in $( find apps ); do
  for input in $( find inputs ); do 
    (
    ulimit -Sf 150 -St 1 -Sd 1024 -Sv 51200
    app < input
    )
    # handle output
  done 
done
```

This works well for most of the apps and inputs (1000+ tests), however certain apps with certain inputs (always the same) have problems and freeze the script.

I have test this manually and found that the ones who freeze have problems (segmentation fault). But this is supposed to happen. I'm using ulimit precisely so I can get an error and move on.

Examples of error message:

```
*** glibc detected *** <app name>: malloc(): memory corruption (fast)  0x00000000022de2f1 ***
```

.

```
*** glibc detected *** <app name>: corrupted double-linked list: 0x0000000001cc3120 ***
```

.

```
*** glibc detected *** <app name>: free(): invalid size: 0x00000000017daf20 ***
```

I tried this in different machines, gcc versions, linux versions. I get repetitions, although in different pairs of app and inputs.

How can I find out what's going on and solve it? Or am I doing something wrong?